# MomentJS convert localized date to UTC

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm currently having the following date string in german format:

```
01.09.2021, 14:28:53 // which means the 1st of September, 2021
```

and I try to parse it to UTC, but unfortunatelly when I do it, it switches days with months.

```
2021-01-09T14:28:53.000Z
```

The code that I have:

```
const date: string = '01.09.2021, 14:28:53';
moment.utc(date).locale('de').toISOString();
```

What I try to achieve is:

```
2021-09-01T14:28:53.000Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your custom format

```js
const date = '01.09.2021, 14:28:53';
const tmp = moment(date, 'DD.MM.YYYY, HH:mm:ss').locale('de').toISOString();
console.log(tmp);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But it isn't really custom. That format is created by momentjs also, and I can't hardcode the date format, because there is also an english language option that works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

No need for moment

```js
const de = true; // as opposed to en = true;
const str = `01.09.2021, 14:28:53`
const [_,aa,bb,yyyy,t] = str.split(/(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4}), (\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})/)
dd = de ? aa : bb;
mm = de ? bb : aa;
console.log(dd,mm,yyyy,t);
console.log(`${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}T${t}.000Z`);
```